# 554 transcation failed error : sending paused for this account

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, web-development-server

I am trying to send an email via aws smtp server at line transport.send it gives the error sending is paused for this account

Comment: could be credentials issues/ or firewall issues. Can you try to send email connecting to was smtp from your terminal or command prompt

Comment: [Has a lot of your mail been bouncing](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-resolve-account-review-pause/)?

Answer (score 1):

Sending got paused for my SES account and I didn't get any notification from AWS. My account was healthy but when I tried sending I kept getting the same error: AccountSendingPausedException (client): Sending is paused for this account. I've fixed it using the aws CLI and running the following commands:

To see if sending is enabled:

```
aws ses get-account-sending-enabled --region <YOUR_REGION>
```

To re-enable sending:

```
aws ses update-account-sending-enabled --enabled --region <YOUR_REGION>
```

Replace <YOUR_REGION> with the region of your SES service, for example `us-east-2`

Comment: Thanks. Checking region in aws is the first few things one should do as , my error from s3 bucket got solved just by correcting my region.

Answer (score 0):

The error was because of bouncing emails and therefore my smtp server was stopped by aws . Solved the error by creating new smtp error.